# how to stop user fill the form when opacity is less than 1

Tags: css

I want the users not to fill the form when `opacity` is less than 1.

```css
.container{
  height: 100px;
  width: 250px;
  background:blue;
  opacity: 0.2
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: You are looking for a JS solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="container">
  <form>
    <input type="text">
  </form>
</div>
<script>
    const container = document.getElementById("container")
    const input = document.getElmentByTagName("input")

    if (container.style.opacity <= 0.1){
        //I think this should be input.disabled = true;
    }
    else {
       //I think this should be input.disabled = false;
    }
</script>
```